# Drop packets using WinDivert

Tags: driver, firewall, dllimport, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to write simple firewall that can drop packet by filter. For this purpose i'm use [WinDivert](https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html). I'm load WinDivert.dll and add WinDivert.lib and  WinDivert32.sys to project folder. Then i try use  WinDivertOpen() to install WinDivertDriver. The result is always negative. 
What do I do wrong and how can I successfully install the driver? Code example.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in the following way. 
**1)** In Project->Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies set path to WinDivert.lib .
**2)** Moved to root folder files WinDivert.dll and WinDivert32.sys.
**3)** Include windivert.h to my project.
**4)** Set my PC in TESTSIGNING Boot Configuration (Use for this Windows Driver Kit 7.1.0.).
**5**) Restart PC.
If these steps did not help you should build WinDivert from sources with Windows Driver Kit 7.1.0. and Visual Studio 12 or higher  as it is described [here](https://github.com/basil00/Divert)

Comment: Note that most users do not need to build WinDivert from source.  Instead, you can just use the official binary releases which do not require TESTSIGNING to work.